# Linear Function:

Tags: functions

Two linear functions $f$ and $g$ having $0$ image of $0$ each are given. If $f(5)=10$ and $g(4)=12$, find the inverse of the linear composite function.

My approach
Since, the two functions $f$ and $g$ are unknown. Let $f(x)=ax+b$ and $g(x)=mx+c$.

But, I could not find the functions $f$ and $g$. Please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Since $f(0)=g(0)=0$ we have $f(x)=ax= 2x$ (from $f(5)=10$) and $g(x)=mx=3x$ ( from $g(4)=12$)

(Anyway: note that a function as $y=ax+b$, with $b\ne0$ is not linear because $y(x_1+x_2)=ax_1+ax_2+b \ne y(x_1)+y(x_2)=ax_1+ax_2+2b$)